# Constraint is sometimes not being strictly adhered to using GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm using Google's ortools for Python to solve a problem.

A constraint that I provide is **sometimes** not being strictly adhered to when running with various data through it.

I've created a test to run 1000 optimisations and change the data input with random values of which the Objective is set to Maximisation. Every now and again the test will fail as one results price is over 1000. It is possible not to go over, so why does it choose to?

How can I enforce the strict use of constraints?

```
# Price constraint - must NOT be more than 1000
cons = solver.Constraint(0, 1000)
```

Comment: AFAIK your knowledge of the solver, and your expectation of what results it should produce, is correct. Can you provide an example that we can replicate & debug on our own? E.g., you said you randomly generated optimizations and checked for failures; can you cherry-pick one that fails, and post its setup / outputs? (The smaller the example, the better. But whatever you can find.)

Comment: This is not helping. Please add an example that let us reproduce the problem, and debug it. General statements like the solver does not do what I want is usually the sign of a wrong model.

Answer (score 1):

```
cons = solver.Constraint(0, 1000)
```

This creates a linear constraint 0 <= (no linear terms) <= 1000.

Is this what you want?